# Multibyte CString to Unicode MFC

Tags: mfc, cstring, multibyte, unicode-string

I have 2 MFC  projects.

A library project uses Multi-byte Character set.

An executable project uses Unicode Character set.

I only wrote the library project and have to use it in the executable. 
One of the library's functions returns a CString. 
When I try to put that CString into a variable in my unicode project and compile
I get this:

```
Error 3 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class  
ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class 
ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __thiscall CTextDisplay::GetString(void)" 
(?GetString@CTextDisplay@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@_WV?  $StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?
$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)
```

I don't mind converting on any of the projects. I just want a way for the library to be able to return a string to the executable project.
Switching either project to the other character set is not an option as they are both gigantic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be really happy just knowing what the type of variable could I stuff the return value into without the linker giving me an unresolved external

Answer (score 0):

There is really no such thing as returning a CString. There are CStringA's and CStringW's and it sounds like you are receiving one and want the other. You will need to use MultiByteToWideChar and/or WideCharToMultiByte to convert.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok just starting with the basic. You say it's either a CStringW or a CStringA and just by doing  either one of these
CStringW val = m_batch.Get_String();
CStringA val2 = m_batch.Get_String(); 

I get a  linker error every time. I don't even know what the type being passed around is

Comment: @irco If the library is compiled with different settings than the exe then the CString definition might be different in the two (and this incompatible). Avoid the problem by returning a (const char*) or (const wchar_t*) instead of a CString.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry if I'm being slow here never had to deal with this stuff. I have the function return an array of chars but all there is in there now is gibberish. Do i need a MultiBytetoWideChar here?